# Match entire words but ignore special characters in regex

Tags: regex

I want to match an entire phrase but ignore the characters `-` and `:`.

For example:

```
Walmart Superstore - match

Walmart: Superstore - match

Walmart - Superstore - match

Walmart -  no match

dkfjsjdf - no match

Superstore - no match
```

How would I do this in regex?

Comment: Easiest way is to strip the characters you don't care about first, then do a match.

Comment: Like this `[^-:]*`? Or the opposite and replace `[-:]` with nothing

Comment: You can use this regex: [`^Walmart[:\s-]+Superstore$`](https://regex101.com/r/dXWpEJ/1)

Comment: Does it need to be case sensitive? Or case insensitive? Should it match `walmart superstore`, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your examples, you can do it like this `Walmart[\s:-]+Superstore`.

https://regex101.com/r/epqiXO/1

Comment: You should show the full regex pattern, including slashes, modifiers (`g`?), etc.

Comment: I get the idea. Thanks!